# Can't find my command "rosinstall"

Tags: ros, rosinstall, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros-electric on my ubuntu10.04 and tried to install the 3D package by writing a t.rosintall file as follow

```
  - svn:
      uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/branches/trunk_diamondback/sandbox/3d_navigation/
      local-name: stacks/3d_navigation
  - svn:
      uri: https://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/octomap_mapping
      local-name: stacks/octomap_mapping
  - svn:
      uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/branches/arm_navigation_metrics
      local-name: stacks/motion_planning_common
```

However when I tried to install the package by the command

```
  rosinstall . /opt/ros/electric/ ./t.rosinstall
```

It showed:

```
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros$ rosinstall ./opt/ros/electric/ ./t.rosinstall
  rosinstall: command not found
  bcddivad@bcddivad-laptop:~/code/ros$
```

Then I tried
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-*

but still in vein.
Can anyone please help me?

Thanks to @Dan Lazewatsky

And for those who haven't installed pip , please view [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32329/can%27t-find-my-command-%22rosinstall%22/) by [bcddivad](https://answers.ros.org/users/2223/bcddivad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-04-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosinstall is not installed as part of the debian packages. You can install it with pip as follows

```
sudo pip install -U rosinstall
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5